# How to customize the Toggle button with a viewpager in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, android-togglebutton

I need to embed a `Toggle` button in an `Activity` which also has a `ViewPager` inside it. I can easily change the `Button` (Not the Toggle) color on `OnPageChangeListner` of `ViewPager`. So, I think it would be applicable for `Toggle` button as well. Please correct me here, If I am wrong.

How can I customize the `Toggle` button which looks similar to this image:

[image]

Any help or hint would be appreciable. Thanks!

Comment: Do you a have problem because of swipe or looking for a way to implement custom toggle button ?

Comment: First, I want to design the custom toggle button. Then I will try to implement it with the viewPager :)

Comment: implementing toggle button in viewPager is not an issue i send you a custom toggle button xml code and then you can use it in activity,fragment or ....

Answer (score 0):

```
<com.stackoverflow.customtoggle.Widget.MySwitch
            android:id="@+id/cb_map_visibility"
            style="@style/mySwitchStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="42dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            mySwitch:textOff=""
            mySwitch:textOn=""
            mySwitch:textOnThumb="false"
            mySwitch:thumb="@drawable/switch_thumb"
            mySwitch:track="@drawable/switch_track" />
```

where drawable('switch_thumb') refer to an image and textOff and textOn help you put Text inside switch button.

MySwitch class is a extension of CompoundButton.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer but How can I add text to it ?

Comment: using textOn and textOff

Comment: Oops! I didn't see it before. I will test it later but what is `mySwitchStyle`?

Comment: mySwitchStyle contains textOnThumb,thumbExtraMovement,thumbTextPadding,switchMinWidth,pushStyle or anything you want and need to make it more customize